# How to find host original IP from A proxy IP in JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, networking, ip

I am using a IP location Service. which return location of the Ip. But When some proxy user login My site return wrong address Because the IP is Proxy. How to find out the user using proxy IP and find server Ip From Proxy IP in Javascript
.

Comment: can't, that's the point of a proxy

Comment: Pretty much everyone on the internet today is using a proxy, even if just a home NAT.

Answer (score 0):

While the point of a proxy, as Ryan says, is to block this, in some browsers it is possible to use `RTCPeerConnection` to get the user's IP.

This is not a perfect solution, and can be blocked fairly easily. Firefox has a built in setting to turn it off, in Chrome uBlock Origin can be used to block it.  To check if your browser is vulnerable you can use [this page](https://diafygi.github.io/webrtc-ips/), or take a look at the [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/diafygi/webrtc-ips).